# How does one solve a 2nd order Euler equation (ODE) that has no x on the 2nd term?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Currently doing differential equations and I ran into an Euler equation, that has no x on the 2nd term. So the differential equation looks like this:

**x²y'' + 7y' + 10y = 0**

I have no idea how you'd even approach this problem, I mean I assume it will most likely be some substitution, but I have no clue what kind of a sub will make this equation work.

Comment: Are you sure that this is not a typo? As it is, it is a properly singular DE, without any easy solution.

Comment: @LutzLehmann Yeah I am sure, there's another equation of the same type right below it. I'm very confused by this since there's no mention of how to solve these types of equations up to this point. I mean I guess it could be a double typo, but I doubt it.

Comment: It is quite possible that such a copy-paste error remains undetected if both equations have similar shape. That the pattern is similar gives a reciprocal confirmation that the other equation is correct. If the topic is Euler-Cauchy, give the solution with the added $x$ and make a try via (Frobenius) power series or WKB approximation to get a handle on the equation as it is.